# How do I replace NaN with 0 when doing division in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am trying to do simple division using .map() on an array of objects. However when zero divided by zero returns NaN. How to I check for this calculation and return the number 0 instead of NaN?

```
  mounted() {
        console.log(this.dataOverview);
       let newData = this.dataOverview.map((data) => { 
           return {
              conversationSource: data.conversationSource,
              Id: data.Id,
              answerableConversations: data.conversationCount,
              interactiveConversations: data.interactive,
              leads: data.sent,
              interactiveLeadConversations: ((data.sent / data.interactive) * 100).toFixed(0) 
            }
        })
        this.convertedData = newData;
        console.log(this.dataOverview);
    }
```

Using this, interactiveLeadConversations returns NaN when both data.sent and data.interactive are zero.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to explicitly check. This should be your line 10:

```
interactiveLeadConversations: (((data.sent / data.interactive) || 0) * 100).toFixed(0)
```

What I'm doing here is to replace the expression

```
(data.sent / data.interactive)
```

with

```
( (data.sent / data.interactive) || 0 )
```

`NaN` evaluates to `false`, so if the expression `(data.sent / data.interactive)` equals `NaN`, you are offering `0` as alternative.

Comment: Only other falsy number is `0` and `-0`, and obviously that's not a problem here.